# WSO2 API Manager - Error! You have partially-created keys. Please click the Clean Up button and try again

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have problem, I was create SSL on API Manager, but my Issue is All APplication can not generate Token and Show Message as this Image. and Alert as is : Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKeyByApplicationId

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in wso2carbon.log file? If so please provide stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error you observed might be due to the user does not have a particular role assigned.

Can you please manually assign the role to the user by logging into the Management Console and see whether the issue gets resolved or not?

In order to further check please provide the log file as mentioned above.

Comment: this problem was solved with check api-manager.xml

Find and change if not same with this url
 <AuthManager>
        <!-- Server URL of the Authentication service -->
        <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>

Sory for my english

Comment: I am using APIM 2.6.0, login as Admin in /store, create an app for admin, when generating keys it has the same error and cannot be cleaned up.